# Scaffolding on Windows 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Does anybody try used MvcScaffolding/T4Scaffolding with Visual Studio 11 beta and Windows 8 Customer Preview? For me when I write:

```
Scaffold CustomScaffolder SomeScaffold
```

there is no result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try to install MvcScaffolding from NuGet, I get the message:

```
Sorry, T4Scaffolding and MvcScaffolding currently do not support preview 
versions of PowerShell 3 (for example, on prerelease copies of Windows 8).
```

It appears we will need to wait for an update from the authors. You can contact them through the [MvcScaffolding NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/mvcscaffolding) to request an update.

Comment: The new versions of MvcScaffolding 1.0.8 (https://nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding/) and T4Scaffolding 1.0.7 (https://nuget.org/packages/T4Scaffolding) solve the preview version of PowerShell issue.